# How to specify the module name with a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I try to load an image with the following code, the src part will not load the module but the `src='sea'` and the image will not load.

What can I do to improve this situation?

```
import forest from '../media/forest.png'
import sea from '../media/sea.png'
import name from './item.jsx'

const app = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <img src={name('sea')} />
            </div>
        )
}

-------item.jsx-------

export const name = (text) => {
        if (text === 'sea') {
            return 'sea'
        } else if (text === 'forest'){
            return 'forest'
        }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your `name` function is doing. Why not simply write `src={image1}`?

Comment: The example sentence was wrong, so I corrected it.

Comment: At the moment you're returning strings from that function. What happens if you just return the variable instead: `return sea`?

Comment: Since the name is loaded from another page, I get the error 'sea'is not defined.

Answer (score 3):

You should return the `reference` not the `string`

So It should be

```
return sea;
```

not

```
return "sea";
```

**NOTE:** It would be better to make it an object and return the value as `dict[text]` If you want to create a function that will return `name`. This is more readable and maintainable code.

```
const name = ( text ) => {
    const dict = { sea, forest };
    return dict[text];
}
```

Thanks for the suggestion [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1377002/andy): You can also do as

```
import forest from '../media/forest.png'
import sea from '../media/sea.png'

const dict = [sea, forest];

const app = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={ dict( 'sea' ) } />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I'd probably put `dict` outside the function. Makes it easier to test.